# Java Output Looping Issue

Tags: java

My goal is to make a calendar application with an output that will wholly display a year's calendar. Something just like this essentially-

```
         January   2000        February   2000        March   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S| |S  M Tu  W Th  F  S| |S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
                   1         1  2  3  4  5            1  2  3  4 
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8   6  7  8  9 10 11 12   5  6  7  8  9 10 11
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  13 14 15 16 17 18 19  12 13 14 15 16 17 18
16 17 18 19 20 21 22  20 21 22 23 24 25 26  19 20 21 22 23 24 25
23 24 25 26 27 28 29  27                    26 27 28 29 30 31
```

but when Using my code below, I get an output that looks like this to my utter disbelief.

```
         January   2000        February   2000        March   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S||S  M Tu  W Th  F  S||S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
                   1        1  2  3  4  5           1  2  3  4 
                   1        1  2  3  4  5           1  2  3  4 
                   1        1  2  3  4  5           1  2  3  4 
                   1        1  2  3  4  5           1  2  3  4 
                   1        1  2  3  4  5           1  2  3  4 
     April   2000        May   2000        June   2000   
|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S||S  M Tu  W Th  F  S||S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|
                   1     1  2  3  4  5  6              1  2  3 
                   1     1  2  3  4  5  6              1  2  3 
                   1     1  2  3  4  5  6              1  2  3 
                   1     1  2  3  4  5  6              1  2  3 
                   1     1  2  3  4  5  6              1  2  3
```

I can't seem to identify where the issue is and was wondering if there were any suggestions for how to fix it and make it work properly. I feel like I didn't implement a loop properly and decimated all flow in my code but im not sure anymore.

```
public class Calendar {
    public String calender;
    /***************************************************************************
        *  Given the month, day, and year, return which day
        *  of the week it falls on according to the Gregorian calendar.
        *  Returns 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, and so forth.
        ***************************************************************************/
    public static int day(int month, int day, int year) {
        int y = year - (14 - month) / 12;
        int x = y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400;
        int m = month + 12 * ((14 - month) / 12) - 2;
        int d = (day + x + (31 * m) / 12) % 7;
        return d;
    }

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))
            return true;
        if (year % 400 == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // take in command line argument to determine the month and year
        int month = 0;
        int year = 2000;
//      try
//      {
//       year = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // year
//      } catch(Exception e) {
//          System.out.println();
//          System.out.println();
//          System.out.println("Usage: Calender.java [Year<integer>]");
//          System.out.println("-h            Open Usage Directions");
//          System.out.println();
//          System.out.println();
//          System.exit(0);
//      }
        // months[i] = name of month i
        String[] months = { "", // left empty so that months[1] = "January"
                "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
                "November", "December" };

        // days[i] = number of days in month i
        int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

        for (month = 1; month < 11;) {

            // check for leap year
            if (month == 2 && isLeapYear(year))
                days[month] = 29;

            // print calendar header
            for (int f = 0; f < 3; f++) {

                System.out.print("     " + months[month] + "   " + year + "   ");
                month++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            for (int f = 0; f < 3; f++) {
                System.out.print("|S  M Tu  W Th  F  S|");
            }
            System.out.println();

            // print the calendar


             for (int calendarLine = 1; calendarLine <= 5; calendarLine++) {
                 month-=3;
            for (int f = 0; f < 3; f++) {
                int d = day(month, 1, year);
                for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
                    System.out.print("   ");
                for (int l = 1; l <= days[month]; l++) {

                    System.out.printf("%2d ", l);

                    if (((l + d) % 7 == 0) || (l == days[month])) {
                        if(month<12)
                        month++;

                        break;
                    }
                }
                }   System.out.println();

             }



        }
```

Comment: Could you add some complete code that compiles?

Comment: @toastedDeli done

Comment: You are increment `month++;` external to the `for` loop. You then continue to use it later. Probably not a good idea. You should introduce another variable for this.